# How to store iBeacon RSSI values till one minute in an array using python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I have 10 Beacons and I can see there are different rssi values published using python file.

however, when i try to use the phone/pc to find the beacons, sending different "rssi" value for unique mac address.

I need to understand that is there any function to find value of rssi for unique mac address? Below is my output and should I get value of rssi in one array for one mac address?

For Example

Message Recieved from Beacon: {
 "uuid": "uuid",
 "major": 1,
 "minor": 2,
 "txPower": 216,
 "RSSI": -76,
 "MAC_ADDRESS": "ca:83:81:d8:f4:2f"
}

Message Recieved from Beacon: {
 "uuid": "uuid",
 "major": 1,
 "minor": 2,
 "txPower": 216,
 "RSSI": -77,
 "MAC_ADDRESS": "ca:83:81:d8:f4:2f"
}

I expect the output

In one minute duration

Mac address : [ca:83:81:d8:f4:2f]
RSSI        : [-76,-77,-78]

Answer (score 0):

Each "message received" is an advertising data packet.  It contains the signal strength of that particular packet as the RSSI value.  The advertisements come in random order and aren't requested for by the receiver.  If you want to query a particular address for the last few RSSI values, then you need to have the program record all the advertising RSSI values it's previously seen and then you query that.